# How to show changes made to component in engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update a button I have made in my separate project component. When I make changes to the button, and push the changes to the appropriate branch I am unable to see changes to the button.

I have tried running several different terminal commands such as: npm run build:development and bundle exec rake assets:preocompile to no avail. I am new to Ruby and Ruby on rails development in general, so I am not sure if I am making a simple mistake.

[Image of what is shown on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjS2h.png)

Engine (ion-testing-engine):

```
"dependencies": {
    "orion-testing-js": "git://github.cerner.com/orion/orion-testing-js.git#ION-26325",
    "orion-sso-js": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

Component (orion-testing-js):

```
return (
    <ContentContainer>
      <Button text=" Hello World!" />
    </ContentContainer>
  );
```

The previous button name was "World". That is shown but will not update. I am wanting to be able to make changes to my component and see those changes on my localhost page.

Comment: what is github.cerner.com ?? not reachable for me

Comment: @lacostenycoder github.cerner is the server my companies runs off of. The code in that branch is the exact same as the code shown in the component. You cannot connect to the github unless you are on the company wifi.